# Filter JSON response for a substring in value

Tags: javascript, json

I'm running an `OCR` job that returns all detected text in `JSON` formatted response.
Excerpt here:

```
     { BlockType: 'WORD',
       Confidence: 99.76903533935547,
       Text: 'SALES',
       Geometry: [Object],
       Id: '5ec23a08-9414-4b5c-99e7-1eae56bdc50a' },
     { BlockType: 'WORD',
       Confidence: 99.61475372314453,
       Text: 'TAX',
       Geometry: [Object],
       Id: '564594a4-32d6-4a24-aaf6-76ac2794dfbb' },
     { BlockType: 'WORD',
       Confidence: 98.65728759765625,
       Text: '-7.94',
       Geometry: [Object],
       Id: 'f9c94902-4807-43a2-b834-b68d52f00efc' },
     { BlockType: 'WORD',
       Confidence: 99.82821655273438,
       Text: 'TOTAL',
       Geometry: [Object],
       Id: '8515e57f-fe6f-4c13-b2d0-c0dcb82333bb' },      
     { BlockType: 'WORD',
       Confidence: 98.82560729980469,
       Text: '-$140.32',
       Geometry: [Object],
       Id: 'e7ba0d15-678a-4b30-a764-0a41d7f89f29' },
    { BlockType: 'LINE',
        Confidence: 96.75798797607422,
        Text: 'CASHIER: JSMITH',
        Geometry: { BoundingBox: [Object], Polygon: [Array] },
        Id: 'f50c8a71-6954-428f-8d61-8a143194befd',
        Relationships: [ [Object] ] }
```

I need to filter out for a field that `"matches"` a certain prefix string.

These work perfectly for fields that match EXACTLY...

`var data2 = data.filter(d => d.Text == 'SALES');`

`var data2 = data.filter(d => d.Text == 'TAX');`

But not so much for the `CASHIER` field.

I tried several ways...to no avail.. including..

`var data2 = data.filter(d => d.Text.includes('CASH') );`

`var data2 = data.filter(d => d.Text.match('CASH') );`

Anything that's not a comparison operator generates this type of error...

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined`

Any thoughts on how I can do a `"like 'CASH' "` filter on the `JSON` ?

Comment: What environment are you running this in (ie browser, NodeJS) and what version?

Comment: Judging from what you've provided, I can only guess that _some_ of your elements do not have a `Text` property which is fine for a comparison but obviously generates an error when you try and use a `String.prototype` method. Try adding `d => typeof d.Text === 'string' && d.Text.includes('CASH')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be getting below error because in the data text key will be having a null or undefined value

So you can modify your code to archive desirable results.

```
var data2 = data.filter(d => d.Text && d.Text.startsWith('CASH'));
```

Comment: I don't think OP necessarily wants `startsWith` but otherwise, I suspect this is correct

Comment: I used starts with because,in the question it's mentioned `filter out for a field that "matches" a certain prefix string.`

Comment: Too true, they did say _"prefix"_. You've nailed the real problem though with the `d.Text` _truthy_ check

Comment: Thanks everyone! That '&&' addition worked like a champ! This is a Lambda function running a Textract operation. Much appreesh!

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```js
var data = [{
  "Text": "SALES"
 },
 {
  "Text": "TAX"
 },
 {
  "Text": "-7.94"
 },
 {
  "Text": "TOTAL"
 },
 {
  "Text": "-$140.32"
 },
 {
  "Text": "CASHIER: JSMITH"
 }
];

var res = data.filter(d => d.Text.startsWith('CASH'));

console.log(res);
```